# Double EOL in regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to insert some additional text after double EOLs in the string. I met strange behaviour: when I positive lookahead for occurence of symbol after double EOLs, all is working *almost* fine:

```
"A\n\nA".gsub /(^{2})(?=A)/, '♻'
# ⇒ "♻A\n\n♻A"
```

There is a weird match at `\A` (the begginning of string), but it’s OK with me for now. The real problem occurs when I try the negative lookahead:

```
"A\n\nA".gsub /(^{2})(?!B)/, '♻'
# ⇒ "♻A\n♻\n♻A"
# WHAT?  ⇑
```

Would you please explain me <strike>what I misunderstood in regexps, why the middle match occurs and</strike> how am I supposed to substitude double EOLs with what I need.

**UPD** The middle match occurs because `^` is the metacharacter, matching no-thing, thanks @bsd. What’s the proper way to substitute the double EOLs, though? I’m likely stuck with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhmmm… It states in front of `.gsub`.

Comment: @muda.. I feel sleepy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wrong to assume that `^` can be greedily matched. ^ matches beginning of line.

`^` is also a  metacharacter which matches the zero-width positions between characters. How many zero width positions are there between consecutive newlines/start characters ? It is probably going to match just before each one of the characters.

Look at this

```
"A\n\nA".scan /(^{2})(?!C)/
=> [[""], [""], [""]]
```

You probably meant it to be

```
"A\n\nA".gsub /([\n]{2})(?!C)/ , "\\1♻'"
=> "A\n\n♻A"
```

Edit:

So if you want it across all platforms. You could write it as:

```
"A\r\n\r\nA".gsub /((?:\r?\n){2})(?!C)/ , "\\1♻"
=> "A\r\n\r\n♻A"

"A\n\n\n\nA".gsub /((?:\r?\n){2})(?!C)/ , "\\1♻"
=> "A\n\n♻\n\n♻A"
```

Edit2:
@Alan Moore says that in Ruby 2.0, you could simplify the above regex to

```
"A\n\n\n\nA".gsub /(\R{2})(?!C)/ , "\\1♻"
```

Comment: Well, I know about `[\n]{2}`, but the string comes from the user input, which on different platforms …you know. Thank you for a suggestion about metacharacter match, I definitely miss that.

Comment: And if you're running Ruby 2.0 or later, you can use `\R{2}` to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AlanMoore ! Would you please arrange it as an answer, I’ll accept.

Comment: @bsd There are MacOSs as well, and, finally, this mess of `\r`s and `\n` is definitely not what I want to have in my code. Alan gave an excellent suggestion.

Comment: I think this answer is good enough.  Adding my own just to mention the `\R` option feels like poaching.